# Comparing fan overlap between two Facebook pages

Tags: analysis, facebook-opengraph, facebook-page, social-graph

What's the best way to compare the fan overlap between two pages? For instance, if I were analyzing Coke and Pepsi, how could I find the:

1) Number of fans that like both pages
2) The demos of the fans that like both pages
3) The names of fans that like both pages (although I would expect that this is protected for privacy purposes)

Thanks.